# A function to join two linked lists

Tags: c, list, function, data-structures, linked-list

I implemented the list using

```c
typedef int type;

typedef struct node{
    int val;
    struct node *next;
} node;

typedef struct list{
    node *head;
}listtype ;
```

(The typedef `type` is just there so I can change the datatype of the list by just changing that one line)

And I implemented an `insert` function using

```c
void insert(listtype *l, type elem, int pos) {
    node *p = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    p->val = elem;
    if (pos == 0) {
        p->next = l->head;
        l->head = p;
    }
    else {
        node *q;
        int i;
        for (q = l->head, i = 0; i < pos - 1; i++) {
            q = q->next;
        }
        p->next = q->next;
        q->next = p;
    }
}
```

The `join` function I came up with looks like this

```c
void list_join(listtype *l,listtype *c) {
    if (list_empty(*l)) {
        printf("List empty");
    }
    else {
        node *q;
        int i = 0;
        q = l->head;
        while (q->next != NULL) {
            insert(&c ,q->val, i + list_size(*c));
            q = q->next;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work, or more accurately when I put it through my list view function it doesn't print out the correct contents (or anything at all really).

My function that prints the contents of the list:

```c
void list_view(listtype l) {
    if (list_empty(l))
        printf("List empty");
    else {
        node *q;
        q = l.head;
        int i = 0;
        while (q->next != NULL) {
            printf("%d \t %d \n", i, q->val);
            q = q->next;
            i++;
        }
        printf("%d \t %d \n", i, list_tail(l));
    }
}
```

I'm want to assume this function works properly and the issue is in the join function, but that's giving it a lot of credit.

Comment: If you want to join two lists then you need not to allocate new nodes. Ir you should create a entirely new list that will contain concatenated two lists.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: It isn't quite clear what you mean by joining two lists. Specifically, it isn't clear what is your plan regarding the original lists. Should they both remain intact after the join operation? Should they be destroyed and the joined list assembled from their parts?

Comment: My bad, the join list function is meant to copy the contents of the first list and add it to the end of the second.

Comment: So you change one list and keep the other intact. This asymmetric definition is rather strange.

Answer (score 0):

The logic in the `else` block of the `list_join` function has a few issues:

- The `while` condition should not test the `->next` member, but the node itself, otherwise you'll not insert the tail value of the first list.
- The `insert` function expects a `listype*` argument, not `listype**`, so you shouldn't pass `&c`, but `c` as first argument.
- As in each iteration of the loop the `c` list will get longer, it is wrong to do `i + list_size(*c)`, since **both** `i` and the size of the list will have increased. You'll want to calculate the length of the `c` list only once, and treat that as a constant that applies to all iterations equally. You could even initialise `i` with that list size instead of 0.

Here is a correction:

```
        node *q;
        int i = list_size(*c); // <-- get the list size only once
        q = l->head;
        while (q != NULL) { // No ->next
            // Not &c; no list_size call
            insert(c, q->val, i);
            q = q->next;
            i++;
        }
```

This will fix the issue. But please note that there is lot of inefficiency in your approach which could be avoided if you would maintain a reference to the tail node of a list, and keep it updated. Then if you also create a separate method for *appending* a value at the end of a list (instead of providing a position), you can avoid some of the loops you currently have.

Comment: It works fine for me. Of course, I had to add some functions, including `main`, which you didn't provide. See it run on [repl.it](https://replit.com/@trincottrincots/httpsstackoverflowcoma744125175459839#main.c)